Inquiry on how to set up the bypass function through 2 lan ports in a pc
I have 2 LAN ports on the server (eth0, eth1). I want to export the packet that came from eth0 to eth1. Additionally, I want to make it work in the opposite direction at the same time.
Is it possible?

I believe what you probably want is a "Bridge".  This will forward packets that belong on the other side, but not those that do not.  This is normally used in Wifi routers to connect the wired ports and the wifi connections on the same subnet.
If you actually want to forward all packets like a repeater, I would expect to need to write some kernel mode code.  A repeater is not a normal device.  (You might have one to act as an amplifier on a really long run, but you are probably better off switching technology (fiber?) or buying a link-level specific amplifier.)
